# storing template replacement values in a separate file

Tags: python, templates

Using `string.Template` I want to store the values to substitute into the template in separate files that I can loop through.

Looping is the easy part. I then want to run

```
result = s.safe_substitute(title=titleVar, content=contentVar)
```

on my template. I’m just a little stumped in what format to store these values in a text file and how to read that file with python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is call [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization). In this case, you want to serialize a dict, such as

```
values = dict(title='titleVar', content='contentVar')
```

There are may ways to serialize, using XML, pickle, YAML, JSON formats for example. Here is how you could do it with JSON:

```
import string
import json

values = dict(title='titleVar', content='contentVar')

with open('/tmp/values', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(values, f)

with open('/tmp/values', 'r') as f:
    newvals = json.load(f)


s = string.Template('''\
$title 
$content''')
result = s.safe_substitute(newvals)
print(result)
```